# One-to-One and One-to-Many relation between same 2 table

Tags: database-design, one-to-one, many-to-one, db-schema

I am designing Db where It has 2 tables

1. Line Item table
2. Price Table

Each line item can be of type Lot or Unit
Lot is kind of group of Line item having same price. So there is Many Line items to one price relation
and there is Unit Line item where each of will have a different price (so there is one - one to relation)

So now, I have 2 tables with 2 kind of relation ship between them
price(unit) 1 to 1 Line Item
Price(lot) 1 to many Line Item

We have developed a design like below

`LineItemTable(Id,PriceIdfk...)`
and
`Price(Id,Type,CostPrice)`

here type indicate if is Unit or Lot

But it does not fully restrict relationship described above

eg: LineItem Table has 3 rows below

```
(1, LotA, 31)
(2, LotA, 31)
(3, Unit, 32)
```

and Price table will have below 2 records

```
(31,Lot,100$)
(32,Unit, 13$)
```

Imagine changing PriceIdFk on Line Item from 31 to 32, so 2 items belonging to same lot will have different prices which should not happen.

I have tried of creating separate master table as `LineItemType(Id,Type)`
where it will have only 2 records `(1,Unit)` and `(2,Lot)`
and have this Id referred in `PriceTable` having one more column `LineItemTypeFk`, but this does not make much difference as 2 items belonging to same lot can have different price.

I guess I am identifying the entities in wrong way but I could not find any solution where this case fits.

Comment: I don't understand what you're modeling and what the relationships are between the entities you're trying to model.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc, can you please elaborate on which part or where you stuck to understand the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Item ITM is priced at PRI dollars.
--
item {ITM, PRI}
  PK {ITM}
```

```
-- All items in group GRP
-- are priced at PRG dollars.
--
_group {GRP, PRG}
    PK {GRP}
```

```
-- Item ITM is member of group GRP.
--
item_group {ITM, GRP}
        PK {ITM}

FK1 {ITM} REFERENCES  item  {ITM}
FK2 {GRP} REFERENCES _group {GRP}
```

If an item is member of the group,
then the group price applies; otherwise the item price applies.

```sql
-- Item ITM is priced at PRICE dollars.
--
CREATE VIEW item_price
AS
SELECT i.ITM
     , coalesce (g.PRG, i.PRI) AS PRICE
FROM       item       AS i
LEFT JOIN  item_group AS x ON x.ITM = i.ITM
LEFT JOIN _group      AS g ON g.GRP = x.GRP ;
```

Notes

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
FK = Foreign Key
```

---

### Option 2

As per comments below, to keep `GRP` in `item`.

```
-- All items in group GRP
-- are priced at group-price of PRG dollars.
--
_group {GRP, PRG}
    PK {GRP}

-- Sample data
--
(GRP, PRG)
----------
(G00, -1)  -- special group, individual item price applies
(G01, 120)
(G02, 150)
```

```
-- Item ITM, from group GRP, is priced at 
-- individual item price of PRI dollars.
--
item {ITM, GRP, PRI}
  PK {ITM}
```

If an item is member of the group G00, then the item price applies, otherwise the group price applies.

```sql
-- Item ITM is priced at PRICE dollars.
--
CREATE VIEW item_price
AS
SELECT i.ITM
     , CASE WHEN i.GRP = 'G00' THEN i.PRI
                               ELSE g.PRG
       END  AS PRICE
FROM  item  AS i
JOIN _group AS g ON g.GRP = i.GRP ;
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I got you point, will there be any harm placing GroupId  directly in Item table  instead of going for item_group?                                                            Price in table can be of 2 -3 prices like cell price, cost price so I have thought of having tables like below..... LineItemTable(Id,PriceIdfk,GroupIdFk), Group(Id,PriceIdfk) and PriceTable(Id,Cost,sell) so if it has GroupIdFk then go for Group(...) table price else in PriceTable(..). does it have any problem?

Comment: @RashmiMs You could define a generic `GroupID` (none) and then use that as a discriminator to select item pricing. Should work fine.

Comment: I do have one more concern on PriceIDFk in ItemTable(...) as this for non-group items, this  should be unique and will be null for items beloging to groups. Can we impose Non-null unique fk? I can see sql server allows clustered index to create many null Unique keys but , is it good practice to have that combined with Foreign key constraint? Thank you for your time!!

Comment: @RashmiMs No `NULL`s in this story, see Option 2.

Comment: 1/2 That sounds good to avoid NULL values but still unit items are grouped to single group                                                                                                                             As I have mentioned before price will be a separate table as it will have both cost and sell prices and I will have three tables  LineItemTable(Id,PriceIdfk,GroupIdFk), Group(Id,PriceIdfk) and PriceTable(Id,Cost,sell) so if it has GroupIdFk then go for Group(...) table price else in PriceTable(..)

Comment: 2/2  and I will be keeping both GroupIdFK and PriceIdFk as mutually exclusive so either an item can be in group or individual item but not both and I want to make priceIdFk as Unique because it will 1-1 relation between item to price when it does not belong to group , but I want also allow multiple nulls because it will not have value for group items. I agree with your solution of having separate record for items but I am curious if we can make PriceIdfk as unique with multiple nulls (it is foreign key)

Comment: @RashmiMs, RE: "...the multiple NULLs in UNIQUE column... ", MySQL can do it. It is a bad idea, though.

Comment: Yeah, get that..  Thank you for all the help @Damir.  your suggestion helped me :)